# single-line multiple identical regexp matches between boundaries

Tags: regex, replace, delimiter

I'm trying to do a regexp replace of the following string

```
<font color="#AAABBB">ABABBAABBBAAABAABABABBBAABAAAABAABBAABABABAABABABBABABBBBABABAABAABBAAAABBBAAAAAAABAAAABBABBBBBBB</font><font color="#ABABBB">ABB</font><font color="#AAAAAA">B</font><font color="#BBBAAA">B</font>
```

so that for each and every 'A' and 'B' inside a font tag, the instance is replaced with a

```
<span>A</span> or <span>B</span>
```

which is not so straight forward since the 'color' tags have As and Bs in them, and I just can't globally replace A and B.

Solution is very simple to pull with a two step replacement, looking for

```
(\>)(.*?)(\<)
```

and then replacing

```
([A|B])
```

but I'm trying to understand if it can be done in a single line, for example using https://regex101.com/, to avoid using the command line, and to understand if there's a technique to 'feed' an expression to a regexp, for example with 'recurse', 'lookahead' or 'lookbehind'.

My searches for the above haven't produced meaningful results.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: In general, it is possible. What have you tried? Why do you mention a command line? What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Are you after something like `(color="#[AB]+">)|(A|B)` with `\1<span>\2</span>` as replacement? Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/3c7MJY/2/)

Comment: Sorry I didn't clearly specify:I am only trying to replace A and B inside the font tag's TEXT, not inside the color attribute or other properties, and I have tried using OR and other standard matching flavours, but they don't cut it. The closest I've gotten is this: https://regex101.com/r/CG7ZBZ/1 but as you can see, > and < are not 'mandatory' so I don't know how to use them as actual boundaries (as if they were ^ and $, for example)

Comment: see if this works: `(?<=\>)(A|B)*(?=\<)` (Demo)[regex101.com/r/CG7ZBZ/2]

Comment: @CooperativaItaca in my example every A and B's between `color="#AB...">` and `</font>` are replaced..?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness you're right thanks for the help